# Jenkins xcodebuild failed

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcodebuild

I am configuring Jenkins for iOS development. On the build machine, the following build is successful. But when it's built via shell on Jenkins, it failed. Can anyone help with this? Thank you so much.

```
xcodebuild -workspace CompanyReviews.xcworkspace -scheme CompanyReviews -configuration Debug -destination generic/platform=iOS build
```

[image]

Comment: does your machine that the build run on have the provisioning profiles installed? you normally configure an exportOptions.plist with details of which profile to use

Comment: The signing step needs access to keychain. Try to inlock keychain before running the build.

Comment: @Sulthan 's answer is the solution for my case. Thank both of you. But I mean Jenkins should tell me more details about the problem. Otherwise, I found some useless solutions like 'rebooting my mac, unlocking and locking keychain...which is in a wrong direction

Answer (score 0):

Please check comments above. It's due to keychain issue. Please unlock the keychain with shell before xcodebuild.

the unlocking code is here:

```
PASSWORD="This is your mac password"

security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k $PASSWORD -t private /Users/michaeljordan/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
```